# Having two variables mirror each other

Tags: c#, class, reference

```
class InputBox : TextBox
{
    private object value;

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);

        try
        {
            value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value.GetType()).ConvertFromString(Text);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Utils.offensiveMessage("Invalid format! This field accepts only " + value.GetType().Name + "!");
            Focus();
            Text = value.ToString();
        }          
    }

    public InputBox(object value) : base()
    {
        this.value = value;
        initializeComponent();
    }

    private void initializeComponent()
    {          
        Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This class here takes an object as an input, represents it as a string and then makes sure that whatever is written in the textbox stays of the same type. It has it's limitation as to what types it can handle (value-types only), but I'm working within those confines. Why do I need this?

I have a large class that has a lot of subclasses that all in the end contain value-types. What I want is to present that data to the user and enable him to edit it. This is kind of an atom of my UI.

What would be great here is a way for a variable that I have in my large class to be mirrored by the variable in the above displayed class. When I change one in the little class, the one in the big class is changed in the same manner.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using events on the large class and listen in the small class?

Comment: I'd like to avoid modifying the large class since I'd have to write over 200 events/listeners.

Would reflection work? Would it be bad practice? I could pass the class and the field. I would extract field name as a sting and get it in the class. Then I'd have a reference to the field. And I'd just have to implement it in the small class

Comment: Not sure I get your point correctly. So you have got a large class and several small classes. Each small class contains some data, which is value-type, that needs to be edited by user. Now you need a way to expose the data in small classes in above `Input` UI for user editing while keeping the large class and small classes unchanged?

Comment: No. Small classes represent data of large class. When data in small class is changed, I want the data in large class to change in the same way. And I want to do it without any major modifications to large class.

Comment: Please don't do `catch (Exception e1)`. It's a poor practice and will make your code **more** buggy. You don't want to swallow up exceptions - it just hides them when trying to debug. If there is a way to code so that you don't get exceptions then that is 100x better.

Comment: This is a completely solved problem for Windows Forms - Use `IDataErrorInfo` & `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your data object and bind to the standard controls.

Comment: Can it be done directly with fields (not properties)?

Comment: I'll specify exeption to can't parse or whatever the appropriate exception is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper that implemented an observer-pattern type interface.

Wrapping the object made sure that even value-types were passed as references (since I was now passing the wrapper instead of the value).

I setup the observer pattern so that the observed wrapped object could notify any observers which would then update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using Winforms Databinding - it does this already with two way notification, if you support INotifyPropertyChanged on the large class.

However, if you don't want to use databinding for some reason, you can consider this as an alternative to just make your code work:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var largeClass = new LargeClass() { Blah = 423 };
        var inputBox = new InputBox<double>(
            () => largeClass.Blah, 
            (a) => largeClass.Blah = a
            );
    }
}
public class LargeClass
{
    public double Blah { get; set; }
}
public class InputBox<T> : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);

        try
        {
            _setter((T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(Text));
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            //Utils.offensiveMessage("Invalid format! This field accepts only " + value.GetType().Name + "!");
            Focus();
            Text = _getter().ToString();
        }
    }

    private Func<T> _getter;
    private Action<T> _setter;

    public InputBox(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter) : base()
    {
        _getter = getter;
        _setter = setter;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Text = _getter().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the data type in the input box will be when I'm initializing it. So I can't specify in the constructor, I have to give it a general type. Is that possible? Or derive a type from an object that will be passed from the upper class.

Comment: Never mind, I just passed the type up until I was in a class that knew the type. However, my changes aren't affecting the initial variable.